# Need a Visio tutorial for getting started

Tags: visio

I am making a design document and I need to draw pictures using Visio. I have searched through the Internet, but there is no getting started guide or tutorial. Can somebody help? I need a tutorial which helps me to draw figures of moderate complexity.

Comment: You might want to try superuser.com as this question probably straddles both domains.

Answer (score 3):

At the surface, this looks like a fairly straightforward question, but I would argue that there are some underlying problems inherent in what you are looking for.  There are a couple of ways to address this question:

First, how to use Visio..  Finding that information is fairly straightforward.  The documentation via the Help menu is handy when trying to determine how to actually add elements, tie them together and define schemas based on those elements (be it an E-R diagram, UML, or some other architectural diagram).  Finding the tutorials you are seeking might be difficult as Microsoft has moved Visio from a standalone product, to a part of the Visual Studio Suite, to part of the Office Suite, back to a standalone product.  I would start my search on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library).  Here are a few resources:

- [Visio Insight](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visio/) - A blog dedicated to using and modifying Visio
- [A portion of the Visio documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa200958(office.10).aspx)

Second, how to you develop diagrams (and perhaps more specifically architectural diagrams).  This falls outside of the realm of Visio and moves more towards fundamentals.  There are a lot of books on UML and diagramming problem domains.  I keep a copy of the [UML Cheat Sheet](http://www.holub.com/goodies/uml/) handy.  The same goes for E-R diagrams as well as other models.

And finally, with a question: What kind of diagrams are you trying to create?  As with all tools, make sure that Visio is the right tool for the job.  Would the table diagraming system in SSMS work for you?  How about the class diagraming system build into Visual Studio?  (and this is just assuming you are using Microsoft technologies in order to develop software).  Visio is great for creating flowcharts and systems diagrams as well -- and those are **much** more straightforward.

As one final note, check out some of the samples that should be included.  [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=716C617E-4F9C-4829-800A-F274B5BE8A1E&displaylang=en) is a link to some (albeit older) sample for Visio that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can always read a book on the tool and that's my personal preference. I learned Visio 2010 by reading the book "Microsoft Press Microsoft Visio 2010 Step by Step"